# Lights for 1 & 2 light up Cable Tester even when Remote is not connected

Tags: ethernet, rj-45, cable-tester

I connected my master up to one end of the wire and I’m surprised that 1 & 2 was lighting up. I double checked if the remote had been connected to the other end and it was not.

I have one of those cheap cable testers with master and remote. I hooked up the master without connecting the remote, to my surprise, the lights 1&2 came on sequentially without hooking up the remote to the other end.

Is this an issue with my cables?

Comment: @Ramhound Updated

Comment: Is this behavior consistent and occurring across multiple cables?

Comment: @music2myear it is not. Other wires work as expected.

Comment: That would indicate the problem is with the wires. A short possibly.